# Обрезать первые два символа в строке

Tags: php

Нужно обрезать первые два символа в строке.

Было

```
$str = 'long text there';
```

стало

```
$str = 'ng text there';
```

Как сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рекомендую воспользоваться [`mb_substr`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-substr.php).

```
$str = 'long text there';
$short = mb_substr($str, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

обрезкой символов занимается команда `substr()`.
Чтобы прочитать ее документацию, достаточно набрать в браузере простой адрес

```
php.net/substr
```

или даже проще - набрать одно только одно слово `substr`, а на открывшейся странице поиска кликнуть в первую ссылку.

на открывшейся странице будут примеры для всех возможных вариантов обрезания строки. То есть, данная ссылка - это универсальный ответ на любые вопросы по обрезанию - три ли символа с конца, или по одному с обоих, или оставить первые 5 символов, и так далее.

Как правильно замечено в другом ответе, для строк в мультибайтовых кодировках, таких как `UTF-8`, следует применять функцию `mb_substr()`